# Large data storage options

Tags: apex

I have a custom object that I'm storing JSON in. The largest field size for text fields is `Text Area (Long)` which has a max size of 131,072. To accommodate more than that I have two fields of that type. I split the value when I save and combine when I read it. There are some use cases where it might need to be longer that what can be stored in even two `Text Area (Long)` fields.

My question is, is there any other features of Salesforce that might be a better fit for my use case? I was thinking about ContentDocument/ContentVersion but that always creates a new version with every update. Since the JSON content can be updated on a semi-regular basis I don't really want to have older versions. I'd have to just create new and delete every time it's updated. Is ContentDocument/ContentVersion still the best option or is there something that would be a better fit?

Answer (score 4):

Your options are limited

- Use `ContentVersion` as either a `ContentDocument` or `ContentNote`. Each can be linked to the custom object via `ContentDocumentLink`

  - This has the advantage of being locatable via SOQL from the custom object record.
  - It also has the advantage of being readily inspectable / downloadable to check for valid JSON or to reformat
  - As you noted, each update creates a new `ContentVersion`. Sadly, you can't use Flow to automate the deletion of older versions but you could use a Scheduled Apex Job. Or, maybe you don't care because your org has sufficient File Storage
- Use `Document`

  - Advantages - no versioning!
  - Disadvantages, tab only available in Classic, not linkable to a record
- Use `Attachment`

  - Advantages - no versioning! Can be child of record
  - Disadvantages; you probably already have the setting to treat Attachments as Files and you wouldn't want to block yourself in the future
- Build an Apex wrapper around the two custom fields on your object `Json0__c` + `Json1__c`.

  - Advantages - no versioning!
  - Disadvantages - you need a common library to take a JSON and span it across the two fields; similarly, a library to merge the two fields into a single JSON string.  If you're using the fflib Domain layer (or something similar), you can wrap this in a way familiar to the rest of your code
  - N.B. Library should be generalized to handle 2,3,4, ... *n* JSON fields

In my org, I had to accept JSON coming in via Platform Events that could be > 128K in length so I went with the last option